# Problems creating a header file and implementation files

Tags: c++, header-files

For this assignment we are required to have a header file, an implementation file, and a main file. I have successfully created the program just using one cpp file and my issues arise when I try to separate it into separate files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
struct card
{
int cardvalue;
card *next;
};
card *start=NULL,*ptr,*temp;
void shuffle(int number);
void displayDeck();
void drawCard();
void deconDeck();
int main()
{
shuffle(1);
displayDeck();
drawCard();
displayDeck();
shuffle(2);
displayDeck();
drawCard();
displayDeck();



return 0;
}
void shuffle(int number)
{
deconDeck();
srand(time(NULL));
int num1=0,t,x,numcards;
   numcards=(number*52)+1; 
    int prevdrawnnum[numcards];
for(x=0; x<numcards; x++)
    {
        prevdrawnnum[x]=0;
    }


    for(t=0; t<numcards; t++)
    {
        num1=rand()%numcards;
        if(prevdrawnnum[num1]==1){
            while(prevdrawnnum[num1]==1){
                num1=rand()%numcards;
            }
        }
        prevdrawnnum[num1]=1;
            ptr = new card;
    ptr->cardvalue=num1;
    ptr->next=NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
        start=ptr;
    else
    {
        temp=start;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
            temp=temp->next;
        temp->next=ptr;
    }

    }
    return;
}
void displayDeck()
{
char suits[4]={'C','D','H','S'};
char ranks[13]={'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A'};
int label=1, num2,suit=0,face=0;
temp=start;
while(temp->next!=NULL)
{

    num2=temp->cardvalue;
    if(temp->cardvalue > 52)
    {
        suit=num2%4;
        face=(num2/4)-13;
        cout<<label<<". "<<ranks[face]<<"-"<<suits[suit]<<"          ";     
        label++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    else
    {
        suit=num2%4;
        face=num2/4;
        cout<<label<<". "<<ranks[face]<<"-"<<suits[suit]<<"          ";     
        label++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(label%4==0)
        cout<<endl;


}
cout<<endl<<"Total Number of Cards: "<<label-1<<endl;
return;
}
void drawCard()
{
char suits[4]={'C','D','H','S'};
char ranks[13]={'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A'};
int num2,suit=0,face=0;
temp=start;
num2=temp->cardvalue;
if(temp->cardvalue>52)
{
suit=num2%4;
face=(num2/4)-13;
cout<<endl<<"Card Drawn: "<<ranks[face]<<"-"<<suits[suit]<<endl;    
temp=start;
start=start->next;
free(temp);
}
else{
suit=num2%4;
face=num2/4;
cout<<endl<<"Card Drawn: "<<ranks[face]<<"-"<<suits[suit]<<endl;    
temp=start;
start=start->next;
free(temp);
}

return;
}
void deconDeck()
{
while(start!=NULL)
{
    temp=start;
    start=start->next;
    free(temp);
}

}
```

Above is the code in one file, could anyone give me some guidance on how to separate it into a header/implementation?

Comment: Your header header file should contain struct, function declaration with .h extension and implementation file should have function definition with .cpp extension

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: @Sniper: Comments are not for answering

Answer (score 0):

In general, a header file's purpose is to declare content. For instance, `struct`and `class` declarations, function prototypes (declaring a function's return type, name and parameters), etc. Another thing of note is that headers should have an header guard surrounding its content, to avoid declaring the same things multiple times.

The cpp file associated to that header file (if any) would contain the implementations of the content declared in the header file. This often sums up to function and method implementations. It must also include the header at its top.

In your specific situation, the `main.cpp` should contain only the `main` function (and the few `include` required for it to run). The header should contain your struct and the function prototypes that you put above your main. Finally, the cpp file associated to the header should contain all functions (except the `main`).

On a side note, it is a good practice to put as few `include` as possible in the header file (often you can include in the cpp file where you implement, or avoid including through forward declarations).

Here's a small example :

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
struct A{
    int b;
};
int foo(int bar);
#endif
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
int foo(int bar) {
    return bar;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
int main() {
    foo(4);
    return 0;
}
```